# How can I move image in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, media-images

I have a image, for example `a\m\amding.jpg` and I am replacing image file in database with `v/o/void.jpg.` How can I move file from `a\m\` to `\v\o` and change her name from `amding` to `void`?
I want to copy first image from her folder, rename.it, and set to other folder.

Comment: I think You are talking about some `her` and may be that `her` has a boyfriend

Comment: do you want to replace that image manually or Programatically .

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually.
If you want to do it pragmatically we have couple of options

The `rename` function does this

[docs rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

```
rename('a\m\amding.jpg', 'v/o/void.jpg');
```

If you want to keep the existing file on the same place you should use `copy`

[docs copy](http://php.net/copy)

```
copy('a\m\amding.jpg', 'v/o/void.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok If you want to move manually then go to

`yourMagento_root/media/catalog/product/a/m/amding.jpg` copy and move

`yourMagento_root/media/catalog/product/v/o/void.jpg`

Comment: There is a way to make it from code?

Comment: I actually want to update a media_gallery image file fileld.

Comment: @ana.coman93 explain in more detail what you want to achieve , do you have any csv files from you want to achieve this ?

Comment: No. I have a shell. I want to change all media_gallery images name (image['file']) for one product. For example if I had a image named image.jpg that is saved in i/m/image.jpg....I want to rename it my_product.jpg and automatically save it in m/y/my_product.jpg

Answer (score 0):

We can use the function copyFile() from Magento\Framework\Filesystem;

```
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
  public function __construct(
        Filesystem $backendFile
    ) {
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    }

 $result = $this->mediaDirectory->copyFile(
            $this->getPath('a/m/', 'amding.jpg'),
            $this->getPath('v/o/', 'void.jpg')
        );
```

This worked for me ! Hope it helps for you